# Underbrace part of an expression

Tags: math-mode, formatting, underbrace

Is there a way to only have an underbrace for part of an expression? I want to only have the brace below the 0's but if I move the 5 out of the `\underbrace` then a gap between the 5 and the 0 appears.

[image: Picture of what I have right now]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your typesetting objective, all you need to do is enclose the entire `\underbrace{...}_{...}` expression in an extra pair of curly braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
5{\underbrace{00\dots0}_{\text{$n$ $0$'s}}}^3 \quad\text{vs.}\quad
 5\underbrace{00\dots0}_{\text{$n$ $0$'s}}{}^3
\]
\end{document}
```